# filtering multiple month views with one filter across several views

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I’ve created several dashboards that contain worksheets that reflect data for either one particular month, or a range of months. For example, worksheets One and Two are showing data only for one particular month. Worksheets three and four are showing a range of dates (6 months’ worth).

Either way, worksheets three and four are showing a date range of six months and their last month is the same month as what worksheets one and two are showing for their one month.

What I’d like to accomplish is to create a filter control where I can select just one month. This filter will then update the views to their respective month, and for the worksheets that are showing a date range will update to the month selected, but also show the previous 6 months.

At current the only way I can think of accomplishing this is by having two separate filters for each dashboard, which is just making things more cluttered/confusing than they need to be.

FYI: the date field is the same dimension across all, so no need to join/blend.

Answer (score 0):

This was accomplished by creating two calculated fields which targeted a date parameter that controlled the date(s) being viewed. Below are the calculated fields

Month Control

```
DATETRUNC('month',[-MasterDate]) = DATETRUNC('month',[Month Control])
```

Month Control Previous 6

```
DATETRUNC('month',[-MasterDate]) <=
DATETRUNC('month',[Month Control]) AND 
DATETRUNC('month',[-MasterDate]) >=
DATETRUNC('month',DATEADD('month',-5,[Month Control]))
```

These were then placed in the Filter window for their respective worksheets and the value accepted as ‘True’. The parameter is then brought into the view and it worked perfectly!!!